# SharePoint Online, Change Column Widths On Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, column

I have created a Custom List via Importing Excel Spreadsheet.

How do I adjust the column widths?

I tried to follow the below link, (my view is AllItems.aspx) and it never shows me the menu outlined in step 4:

[MSDN Blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013) gave me a

Is there no way to increase the width? My columns are incredibly squished.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Online native layout use the HTML5 and CSS3 best pratices to provide a responsive layout, this result that you see is associated the SharePoint List Column grid from the SharePoint native branding layout, and during importing, the selected column type used in your import is a single-line-text (that support with limit of 255 characters).

You can try any solutions not supported by Microsoft, like include a CSS rule to increase the width of columns, or change XSLT schema to forcing the changes, but prevent the negative impacts on all other Lists that consumes AllItems.aspx (based on your example) or other template files that you pretend modifie to satisfy your requirements.

But you may try to access [SharePoint List settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-list-settings-in-sharepoint-online-4d35793b-246e-42a3-990c-563a83795b7f) and change column type that have long text to a multiline-text, with this change, the AllItems.aspx Grid will apply break-line at column type multiline-text.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link for better understanding

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

Comment: Please include more than just a link when you answer. Links can go away. If you were to provide the gist of the material you are linking to, we would have a chance of finding more detail via google, if the link ever dies.

Answer (score -4):

Did you try to change the width by:

**Edit page -> Edit web part -> Change width in Appearance section**

Or else you can change the width using JavaScript. Add a js file and change width using .css method.